# -[NSInputStream read:maxLength:] throws an exception saying length is too big, but it isn't

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, stack-overflow, nsinputstream

I use an `NSInputStream` to read data from a file.  It will crash if `maxLength` is greater than 49152.

When it crashes -- sometimes, but not every time, it gives this message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData initWithBytes:length:copy:freeWhenDone:bytesAreVM:]: absurd length: 4294967295, maximum size: 2147483648 bytes'

From my calculation, 524288 is still less than that maximum, and can fit in the return value.  What did I miss?

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
    switch (eventCode)
    {
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        {
            NSInteger bufferSizeNumber = 524288;   //this one will crash.
//            NSInteger bufferSizeNumber = 491520;  // this one will work.

            uint8_t buf[bufferSizeNumber];
            unsigned int len = 0;

            len = [_stream read:buf maxLength:bufferSizeNumber];   //crashing at this line

            // more code ...

        }
        // more  code...
    }
}
```

Edit:  (I think this is critical part of that behavior)

If I "start" in the background thread then the bufferSizeNumber behaves as described above.  But if I "start" in the main thread, the bufferSizeNumber can go upto 943713 before it crashes.

```
- (void)start
{
    _stream.delegate = self;
    [_stream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                       forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [_stream open];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
}
```

Comment: Your types are wrong: the `maxLength` argument should be unsigned, and the variable capturing the return value _must_ be signed, because negative values are used to indicate a read failure. That wouldn't cause this problem, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is a so called "stack overflow" (you might have heard this before).

Your method allocates a buffer on the stack using a variable length array:

```
uint8_t buf[bufferSizeNumber];
```

When the size of the buffer is so large that it overflows the size of the current stack the behavior is undefined. Undefined behavior might result in a crash or just work as expected: just what you are observing.

512kB is a huge buffer, especially on iOS where background threads get a stack of exactly this size.

You should allocate it on the heap:

```
NSInteger bufferSizeNumber = 524288;
NSMutableData *myBuffer = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:bufferSizeNumber];

uint8_t *buf = [myBuffer mutableBytes];
unsigned int len = 0;

len = [_stream read:buf maxLength:bufferSizeNumber];
// more code ...
```

Comment: @user523234 Do you want some time alone together? :)

Comment: len should be NSInteger, as it can be zero or negative, indicating an error!

Comment: @PeterLapisu Good point, even though not the source of the error the OP experienced.